# SVG custom CSS styles for the <use> element in different context

Tags: html, css, svg

### In Firefox, styling a `<use>` element based on it's parent class works, but in Google Chrome /Safari not. How can I achieve this in a cross browser manner?

### SCSS

```
.column-1 {
  .cls-1 {
    fill: red;
  }
  .cls-2 {
    fill: green;
  }
}

.column-2 {
  .cls-1 {
    fill: blue;
  }
  .cls-2 {
    fill: yellow;
  }
}
```

### HTML

Added the  element in the demo, but it's just a svg element with two paths that each has a class name.

```
<div class="column-1">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-usp_return"></use></svg>
  </div>

  <div class="column-2">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#icon-usp_return"></use></svg>
  </div>
```

### DEMO/Playground

http://codepen.io/anything/pen/kXKZNP?editors=1100

Comment: I can't recall the spec but I think this is just somewhere that FF Is ahead of Chrome. Of course, FF have [**@RobertLongson**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson) on board IIRC.

Comment: @Paulie_D Any thoughts about how to achieve something similar cross-browser?

Comment: Not specifically. Not sure if this is entirely on point but it's useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002046/selecting-subelements-of-an-svg-template-via-css?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of path styles in SVG, just add this to each path tag:

```
style="fill: var(--cls-1)"
```

Then set a class to you SVG tag, as such:

```
<svg class="icon1"><use xlink:href="#icon-usp_return"></use></svg>
```

Finally define your CSS:

```
.icon1 {
  --cls-1: red;
  --cls-2: green;
}
```

Fully working example can be found here: http://codepen.io/westefan/pen/grNvoy

Comment: That is a good solution, unfortunately no IE support, not even the latest... :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no support for CSS variables in IE or Edge: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables

Answer (score 1):

You can add `fill="currentColor"` to the second path of your SVG.

Then in your css file you can write:

```
.column-1 {
  use {
    fill: red;
    color: blue;
  }
}

.column-2 {
  use {
    fill: green;
    color: orange;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example based on your code:

**https://jsfiddle.net/08hk886w/**

Comment: Yes, but this is for the lucky case where I've got only two paths, but this was just I lucky example and I needed this for more paths.